# Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 Over the air installation of apps

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there a way to install signed applications over the air on the *windows 8* and *windows phone 8* platforms?

I'm looking for something similar to [**iOS wireless app distribution**](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad871e) with its **itms-services://** uri scheme. Basically, I want to direct users to a web page where they can download and install a signed application package on their device by clicking a link.

But it seems (from the information I gathered from the available documentation) that Microsoft allow app installation only by using the ***Windows Store***,  or by [***Sideloading***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx) (in the case of Windows RT, 8 Pro and 8 Entreprise) or by [***enrolling users phones for company app distribution***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (in the case of Windows Phone 8).

are these really the only methods available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to link to the store to a specific app?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967553(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: No, the app doesn't exist in the windows store, I have the application's signed package hosted on a webserver and I want the users to be able to download and install it directly from the webserver.

Comment: That is intentionally prohibited. It's only supported on iOS for enterprise applications, so the WP8 Enterprise support is very similar to iOS.

Comment: On iOS I can put the package on a webserver and direct users to a page where they can click a link to install the application. This works, I only need to sign the package of the application with the enterprise certificate we got from apple. But on Windows, it seems I have other steps to do : generate a token (AET), and send the token with the app to the user by _email_ or (sideload the app on Windows8). I'm looking for something similar to the iOS way : simple package (signed with an entreprise cert) that users can install from a website without additional steps (token or sideloading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Phone you could use the [beta testing feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). It will not show in the store and only be available for users you have registered via their Microsoft account formerly Live ID. The app will run through certification and therefore will not be hosted on your own server.

For Windows 8.x you will still have to go the side loading route as there is currently no beta testing feature available.

HTH

Comment: The thing is I don't know the list of persons who will download the application in advance. Anyone who can access the webserver should be able to install the application. For an iOS application we have, we just put the signed package for the iOS app on a webserver with a page containing a link to the plist (itms-services://...) , and anyone who can access the web page can install the application. This is why I'm looking for something similar for Windows8 and Windows Phone.

Comment: @MohamedA. No you can not do an OTA with Windows Phone 8. You could put the XAP/App package incl. Powershell script on your server for your users to download. They could then sideload it themselves. But doesn't one have to add the UDID from the iOS devices to the store account for the app to be installed on it?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Mark. For iOS I think adding the UDID to the store account was needed in the early versions of iOS (or still used for the case of beta testing??). The method I'm currently using  for iOS is described [here](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad871e), I just sign packages with a provisioning profile (created from a certificat on apple's membercenter dashboard), and make them available on a webserver.

Comment: @MohamedA. thanks for the link, it has indeed been a while since I deployed my last iOS app.. I thought that for the Phone there is a similiar [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx) but I don't know of my head of any solution for Windows 8.x

Comment: Thanks @Mark, yes I read that page, I need to send to users the Application Enrollment Token and the package by email (at least for the company hub app). For Windows 8 all the information I found mention only the side-loading technique. So that means it not possible on windows, I just needed a confirmation in case I missed something. Thanks again.